# Mixing future executors

Tags: rust

In a happy world libraries don't spawn futures themselves or heavily depend on tokio/async-std/etc.. right? But how to(at least temporarily) work around the need to mix two executors? I'm using [Riker](https://riker.rs), which creates its own `futures:: executor::ThreadPool` and provides means to spawn futures under that pool, now the problem comes with a future I want to execute that uses a library(fantoccini) that requires tokio, complaining at runtime that there is no tokio reactor running.

For now I'd settle for some quick'n dirty workaround but I guess in the future it requires the library author's cooperation to not be bound to an executor?

Comment: one ugly way is to use futures' channels i.e. run the tokio-dependent future on tokio::spawn and have that send data to a channel and read it out on a future running in Riker's threadpool.